# Safe and convenient hotel locations in or around Cape Town

Tags: hotels, destinations, south-africa, cape-town

What are some good suburbs in or around Cape Town to book a hotel at?

The ideal place should be in a safe suburb and close to Table mountain,the V&A Waterfront and all the amenities.

Comment: Hi Deni, as the question stands it is highly likely to be closed as being not constructive. What a good hotel location is, is very subjective. What you might find a good hotel location, others might not like and vv.

Comment: But but...Ok :'-(

Comment: @Deni Can you make this more specific?  At a first glance V&A Waterfront is about 50km from the Table Mountain, so what does "close" means to you?

Comment: @Karlson it's really not that far, I assure you :)  More like 10km.

Comment: @MarkMayo Could be: https://maps.google.com/maps?ie=UTF-8&q=v%26a+waterfront+cape+town&fb=1&gl=us&hq=v%26a+waterfront&hnear=0x1dcc500f8826eed7:0x687fe1fc2828aa87,Cape+Town,+South+Africa&cid=0,0,13393989667965234293&ei=ygQcUdqpPKPC0QGi1YFg&ved=0CM4BEPwSMAA

Comment: @Karlson - yup, [still less than 10km from the mountain gondola](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Table+Mountain+cable+way+(Bottom),+Cape+Town,+Western+Cape,+South+Africa&daddr=v%26a+waterfront&hl=en&sll=-33.937023,18.418236&sspn=0.030727,0.055747&geocode=FUb--f0doM0YASF_LdXNkSlpVinjdXlhomfMHTF_LdXNkSlpVg%3BFU-w-v0dCRgZASlRsuDyXmfMHTF17FF8owLhuQ&oq=table+mou&gl=us&mra=ls&t=m&z=14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost all hotels in Cape Town can be found in a few key locations, so you don't need to worry too much about which one is safer than the other.

- the first location is around the waterfront, where several big hotels are location (I'll leave names out of this)
- the second area is in the city centre, around the Company Gardens and Green Market square. Great location for some of the old sites of the city.
- Finally, just around the corner down the coast you'll get pockets of hotels - in Sea Point (where I stayed last time I was there), Barry's Bay and Camps Bay.  All are fairly safe (for Cape Town - everything is relative, of course), and more importantly than location, you'll want to make sure your hotel has off-street (locked) parking with key-access.